# Swift Run command line using processing(), but return "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 Permission denied"

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am trying to run command lines in a macOS application after clicking a button. But when I run below codes, it always shows me this error "Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 Permission denied". And, I have disabled the sandbox. Thank you for your help.

```
let command = "/Users/donghanhu/Documents/TestFolder"
var args = [String]()
args.append("ls")
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = command
task.arguments = args
do {
    try task.run()
} catch {
    print("something went wrong, error: \(error)")
}
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: Also note that shell and path expansion are not done by `Process` so the executable that you use will probably have to include the full path to the executable  so you may have to use `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls` since Process doesn't know about a shell's $PATH and doesn't search it.

Comment: @ScottThompson sorry for my stupid mistakes. just fixed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood some features of how `Process` works.  The documentation

> A process operates within an environment defined by the current values
> for several items: the current directory, standard input, standard
> output, standard error, and the values of any environment variables.
> By default, an Process object inherits its environment from the
> process that launches it.

So the process will run within the current directory of the parent process.  It looks like you are trying to change the current directory to

`/Users/donghanhu/Documents/TestFolder`

By using the `launchPath` of the `Process`, but `launchPath` should be set to the *executable* you want to run in the subprocess.  In this case I think you want the `launchProcess` to be `"/bin/ls"` because you are trying to run an `ls` command.

So if you want a Process that will use `ls` to list the content of the folder `/Users/donghanhu/Documents/TestFolder` it would be:

```
import Foundation

let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/bin/ls"
task.arguments = ["/Users/donghanhu/Documents/TestFolder"]
do {
    try task.run()
} catch {
    print("something went wrong, error: \(error)")
}
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Scott, total noob here, so please forgive me if I'm totally misunderstanding this, but I tried your method to run an .app that I've put in my /usr/local/bin/myapp.app and I still get the same error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"

Comment: @Johnson A ".app" file is not an executable.  It's actually what is called a "file package" -- essentially a folder that is treated a special way.  In the Finder, if you right click (or Control-Click) on the package you should see menu item "Show Package Contents".  That would let you see what's in the folder.  The executable is usually in a subfolder called (I think) Contents/MacOS.   If you want to launch an application instead of using Process, you should use "Launching and Hiding Apps" methods documented for `NSWorkspace`

Comment: @ScottThompson Thank you for the tip! I know it's not an executable, I wish it was, but I can't figure out how to pack my python script and all of its dependencies into an executable. Unfortunately I cannot decipher the "Launching and Hiding Apps" documentation either. I can't figure out if I'm supposed to be defining the function myself, or why it doesn't have a body in the docs...